# Error while supplying test assets to the compound protocol using ganache-cli and web3.js

Tags: ethereum, web3js, ganache

I'm trying to supply assets to the compound protocol using this guide:
[Supplying Assets to the Compound Protocol](https://medium.com/compound-finance/supplying-assets-to-the-compound-protocol-ec2cf5df5aa).

1. I created account at https://infura.io/ and got my ProjectID.
2. I cloned https://github.com/compound-developers/compound-supply-examples
3. Executed

```
ganache-cli \
-f https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/<YOUR INFURA API KEY HERE> \
-m "clutch captain shoe salt awake harvest setup primary inmate ugly among become" \
-i 1 \
-u 0x9759A6Ac90977b93B58547b4A71c78317f391A28
```

with my ProjectID in https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/ url

4. After that, i ran `node web3-js-examples/supply-eth-via-web3.js` with generated privateKey on previous step [supply-eth-via-web3.js](https://github.com/compound-developers/compound-supply-examples/blob/master/web3-js-examples/supply-eth-via-web3.js).

And i got an error:

```
My wallet's ETH balance: 100
Supplying ETH to the Compound Protocol...
cETH "Mint" operation successful.
Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? You might also see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the contract you are retrieving data from, requesting data from a block number that does not exist, o
r querying a node which is not fully synced.
    at ABICoder.decodeParameters (C:\Users\adel1\PhpstormProjects\compound-supply-examples\node_modules\web3-eth-abi\lib\index.js:288:15)
    at Contract._decodeMethodReturn (C:\Users\adel1\PhpstormProjects\compound-supply-examples\node_modules\web3-eth-contract\lib\index.js:470:22)
    at Method.outputFormatter (C:\Users\adel1\PhpstormProjects\compound-supply-examples\node_modules\web3-eth-contract\lib\index.js:760:42)
    at Method.formatOutput (C:\Users\adel1\PhpstormProjects\compound-supply-examples\node_modules\web3-core-method\lib\index.js:147:54)
    at sendTxCallback (C:\Users\adel1\PhpstormProjects\compound-supply-examples\node_modules\web3-core-method\lib\index.js:523:33)
    at C:\Users\adel1\PhpstormProjects\compound-supply-examples\node_modules\web3-core-requestmanager\lib\index.js:293:9
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (C:\Users\adel1\PhpstormProjects\compound-supply-examples\node_modules\web3-providers-http\lib\index.js:98:13)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\adel1\PhpstormProjects\compound-supply-examples\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request-event-target.js:34:22)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (C:\Users\adel1\PhpstormProjects\compound-supply-examples\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:208:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (C:\Users\adel1\PhpstormProjects\compound-supply-examples\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:318:14)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\adel1\PhpstormProjects\compound-supply-examples\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\dist\xml-http-request.js:289:61)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1327:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

Seems to be method `cEthContract.methods.mint().send()` executing correctly and balance of ETH wallet is changing. But after that all other methods returning same error (*see above*).

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake, gave answer [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/99746/error-while-supplying-test-assets-to-the-compound-protocol-using-infura-project/99754#99754).

Answer (score 0):

You would have to set the gas limit higher in the transaction options or this might be a bug with ganache-cli. The repository now uses hardhat in the latest commit, which might work better.